# Download CSV file in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, wget

Hello friends I am trying to download a csv file from a external url I try with wget command but I obtain a 400 Error bad request if I paste the url directly in the browser I can download the csv file, is there another way to download this type of file or other solution? I need to have a file with the csv content.

Thanks

Comment: without providing the CSV URL and the code/command you used to download it, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: i don´t put the url because it contains a private token key, i am using wget command with the csv url, it is from import.io website that allow you to convert html table into different formats

Comment: you can mock-up the token.

Comment: ok friend this is the url 
https://data.import.io/extractor/f8b1e4f7-3912-4c8c-b271-0f377e184c4c/csv/latest?_apikey=

Comment: could you paste also the exact `wget` command you run?

Comment: This is the command that i run: wget https://store.import.io/store/crawlRun/c7292314-e650-4f87-972d-9bfc51f7b705/_attachment/csv/ecd01d7e-bbb5-40de-8120-c4092e89d1e9?_apikey='key_number'

Answer (score 0):

Have you escaped all special characters in the url such as & to \& or $ to \$

Comment: this is the url i check it and there isn´t any special only numbers and letters  https://store.import.io/store/crawlRun/c7292314-e650-4f87-972d-9bfc51f7b705/_attachment/csv/ecd01d7e-bbb5-40de-8120-c4092e89d1e9?_apikey='key number'

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to do anything with authentication/cookies, run some tool on your browser (like *Live HTTP Headers*) to capture headers. If you, then, mockup those fields in wget, that would get you very close to be like your "browser". That will also show you if there is any difference in encodings between wget data and browser data.

On other hand, you could also watch the server log files (if you have access to them).